# how to apply genetic algorithm on 2d or multidimesional images for optimisation

Tags: image-processing, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to Code a genetic algorithm in Matlab but really dont know how it works in images and how to proceed? Is there any basic tutorial that can help me understand how to apply GA on images (starting from 2d to multidimentional images ).
That will be a great help for me.
Thanking everyone in anticipations.

Kind Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "apply on images"? What do you want to do with the images?

Comment: @JanŽegklitz to be precise i want to use GA as optimal band selector in hyper-spectral images. any guidance  to the problem will be appreciated. Considering new to GA and HSI, any documentation or tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: So then please edit your question so that it is clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks @JanŽegklitz. learning the norms of the community.

Answer (score 0):

For GA you need two things: a fitness function that can evaluate any solution and tell how good it is, and a representation of your solution so that you can do crossover and mutation. Once you have these, you are good to go. I'm not an expert on image processing so I can't help you with that exactly.

Look at the book [Essentials of metaheuristics](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/) which is a very good resource for start with evolutionary computation (and not only that) in general. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper on this subject which you can find at [the IEEE library](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1260030&tag=1). I believe it solves the problem you vaguely describe.